# нужно отловить запрос в sql

Tags: php, sql, request

нужно отловить запрос в sql, когда ни одно значение в таблице не соответствует запросу. Мб есть какая-нибудь функция в php, которая возвращает true false при обнаружении пункта в бд.

```sql
DELETE FROM `orders` WHERE `orders`.`id`='$id_car' AND `orders`.`id_user`='$id_user'
```

идея такая - если не нашло пункта, то выводит юзеру, что он не может удалить бронь другого пользователя

Comment: А в чем проблема сначала сделать SELECT - выяснить есть ли запись или нет, а потом уже ее удалять?

Comment: При выполнении DELETE возвращается количество удалённых записей. Какая проблема в том, чтобы  сравнить вернувшееся значение с нулём?

Comment: хочу просто знать возможно ли сделать это именно так, как описал я.

Comment: @GansLiber ну так  Akina вам и написал как

Comment: а как добыть мне информацию о количестве удаленных записей? При выводе переменной с запросом, выводится всегда 1 (true), даже если ничего не удалилось.

Comment: FYI еще про то, как получить число затронутых (например удаленных) предыдущим запросом записей - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

сделал как советовал первый комментатор

```
$gg = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `orders`.`id`='$id_car' AND `orders`.`id_user`='$id_user'");
$gg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($gg);

if ($gg){
    mysqli_query($connect, "DELETE FROM `orders` WHERE `orders`.`id`='$id_car' AND `orders`.`id_user`='$id_user'");
} else{
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Это бронь другого пользователя';
}
```